# Cannot set encoded comment for zip archive using sharpZipLib

Tags: encoding, zip, sharpziplib

I need the comment for the zip file to be properly encoded. In particular, I have Greek characters in comment. After creating the zip file, the characters become question marks. Here is the code I use:

```
using var fs = File.Create(fileName);
using var zs = new ZipOutputStream(fs);
zs.SetLevel(0);
zs.ZipCryptoEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; // I tried to set this, but it didn't work
zs.SetComment(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data1, data2));
```

Is there a way to properly encode the Comment?

Update: I also tried to the constructor with StringCodec. It didn't work either.

```
var zs = new ZipOutputStream(fs, StringCodec.Default);
```

Comment: Whatever bytes you put in the comment are what you get back. How are you looking at the comment from the zip file? Do you have the right encoding for your terminal? Try to display what you are giving to `SetComment()` in the same way.

Comment: By the way, having some Greek characters in the text is _not_ encryption. Despite the phrase "It's Greek to me."

Comment: @MarkAdler I see the right string is being set as a comment. I check it this way: `var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(metadata, _settings); zipStream.SetComment(str);` The `str` here is the one I need and it is correct at that moment. However, after the zip file is created I check the comment using a regular zip view (e.g. WinRaR) to see the comment and I see the Comment there with question marks and other incorrect characters. When I try to unzip it using my code, I see the wrong text as expected.

Comment: @MarkAdler I have a text in Greek. It is not just a set of chars ;)

Answer (score 0):

`var zs = new ZipOutputStream(fileStream, StringCodec.FromEncoding(Encoding.UTF8));` solved the issue.